# SQL Join after datetime but before next rows start datetime

Tags: sql-server, subquery, query-optimization, window-functions, self-join

Given two tables Event and Activity, I want to join all of the activities that happened at or after an Event started but before the next Event started. The difficult part is that Events do not have end datetimes only starting.

```
CREATE TABLE Event (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY
  ,start_datetime DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE Activity (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY
  ,log_datetime DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO Event (id,start_datetime)
VALUES (1,'2020-01-01')
      ,(2,'2020-01-01 04:55:15')
      ,(3,'2021-05-01 16:23:45');
      
INSERT INTO Activity (id,log_datetime)
VALUES (1,'2020-01-01 00:00:00')
      ,(2,'2020-01-01 01:20:15')
      ,(3,'2020-01-01 16:23:45')
      ,(4,'2020-02-01 00:00:00')
      ,(5,'2021-05-10 13:00:00')
      ,(6,'2022-02-01 18:30:00');

SELECT
  Event.id AS EventID
  ,Event.start_datetime
  ,Activity.id AS ActivityID
  ,Activity.log_datetime
FROM
  Event
  LEFT JOIN Activity
    ON Activity.log_datetime >= Event.start_datetime
ORDER BY
  Event.start_datetime
  ,Activity.log_datetime;
```

| EventID | start_datetime | ActivityID | log_datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2 | 2020-01-01 01:20:15.000 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 3 | 2020-01-01 16:23:45.000 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 4 | 2020-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 5 | 2021-05-10 13:00:00.000 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 6 | 2022-02-01 18:30:00.000 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 04:55:15.000 | 3 | 2020-01-01 16:23:45.000 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 04:55:15.000 | 4 | 2020-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 04:55:15.000 | 5 | 2021-05-10 13:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 04:55:15.000 | 6 | 2022-02-01 18:30:00.000 |
| 3 | 2021-05-01 16:23:45.000 | 5 | 2021-05-10 13:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 2021-05-01 16:23:45.000 | 6 | 2022-02-01 18:30:00.000 |

The results I am trying to get would be:

| EventID | start_datetime | ActivityID | log_datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2 | 2020-01-01 01:20:15.000 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 04:55:15.000 | 3 | 2020-01-01 16:23:45.000 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 04:55:15.000 | 4 | 2020-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 2021-05-01 16:23:45.000 | 5 | 2021-05-10 13:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 2021-05-01 16:23:45.000 | 6 | 2022-02-01 18:30:00.000 |

I know I could do this with an additional condition on my join, if Events had an end time.

What I am needing to do I think is first get a query to generate Events with the `end_datetime` equal to the following Event `start_datetime`:

| EventID | start_datetime | end_datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020-01-01 04:55:15.000 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 04:55:15.000 | 2021-05-01 16:23:45.000 |
| 3 | 2021-05-01 16:23:45.000 | NULL |

Which I am able to achieve with:

```
SELECT
  e.id
  ,e.start_datetime
  ,MIN(e2.start_datetime) AS end_datetime
FROM
  Event e
  LEFT JOIN Event e2
    ON e2.start_datetime>e.start_datetime
GROUP BY e.id, e.start_datetime
```

So the solution I have is to take the above and form it into a subquery and then join to it the Activity table using the start and now end datetimes:

```
SELECT
  Events.id AS EventID
  ,Events.start_datetime
  ,Events.end_datetime
  ,Activity.id AS ActivityID
  ,Activity.log_datetime
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      e.id
      ,e.start_datetime
      ,MIN(e2.start_datetime) AS end_datetime
    FROM
      Event e
      LEFT JOIN Event e2
        ON e2.start_datetime>e.start_datetime
    GROUP BY e.id, e.start_datetime
  ) Events
  LEFT JOIN Activity
    ON Activity.log_datetime >= Events.start_datetime
       AND (
         Activity.log_datetime < Events.end_datetime
         OR Events.end_datetime IS NULL
       )
ORDER BY
  Events.start_datetime
  ,Activity.log_datetime
```

Is there a better way to do this? I got the result wanted, but it doesn't feel very efficient with the subquery.

I know I can and should add indexes on the `start_datetime` and `log_datetime` columns to increase optimization. But is there any restructure of the query that would also help optimize?

Fiddle Link:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b5639752cc9cba32faee10bf3810d950

EDIT: The IDs of the Events are not always in the same order as the `start_datetime`. An Event will always last until the next event is started. If there is no next event, then the current event is still in progress. The reason that the IDs are not consistent with the `start_datetime` order is because this data is ingested and given auto incremented ids and sometimes the ingestion of Events may come out of sequential datetime order.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify. Does each Event last until the next one, meaning the one with the next highest id, begins? Is the Event with the highest ID still in progress?

Comment: i think this should go in Code Review stack.

Comment: @DougCoats I was not aware of that stack exchange until now. Given that there is a query-optimization tag here, I assumed it was the correct place. Is there a way to move it over there without rewriting it?

Comment: im not sure honestly. I wasnt trying to be harsh or anything I was just saying its probably more appropriate there.

Comment: @DougCoats with respect, I think this is an OK question for [tag:query-optimization]. The questioner asked about programming techniques, and there's a legit answer (LEAD).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the query a bit. Start with this subquery to retrieve your Event table including an end_datetime. Using the [LEAD windowing function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

```sql
      SELECT id, start_datetime, 
             LEAD (start_datetime, 1) OVER (ORDER BY start_datetime ASC) 
        FROM Event
```

Will this make the query faster? Probably: `LEAD()` is generally more efficient than `MIN() ... LEFT JOIN ... GROUP BY` because it has to wrangle less data.

Then use it with your (correct) logic to join the Activity table. Using a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), the query now looks like this.

```sql
WITH StartEnd AS (
  SELECT 
    id, start_datetime, 
    LEAD (start_datetime, 1) OVER (ORDER BY start_datetime ASC) end_datetime
  FROM Event a
)
SELECT StartEnd.id EventId, StartEnd.start_datetime, StartEnd.end_datetime,
       Activity.id ActivityId, Activity.log_datetime
  FROM StartEnd
  LEFT JOIN Activity 
           ON Activity.log_datetime >= StartEnd.start_datetime
          AND (    Activity.log_datetime < StartEnd.end_datetime
                OR StartEnd.end_datetime IS NULL) 
ORDER BY StartEnd.start_datetime, Activity.log_datetime;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7bed10458d71517c58124671ca7e4dee)

I suspect an index on `Event (start_datetime)` will help. And so will an index on `Activity(log_datetime)`. You can omit `id` from those indexes because `id` is the PK on both tables and is implicitly part of any other index.

But to be sure, when you run this query *with your real data* in SSMS, right-click in the query window, choose Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query and examine the plan. Those Actual plans sometimes suggest appropriate indexes.

Common Table Expressions definitely make queries easier to read. And the way the query planner works, they don't harm performance compared to using subqueries.